# user-defined function that manipulates and returns XML from a stored procedure

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, t-sql, recursion

I want to do something like this in a stored procedure where `dbo.Ordex_Select_Things_as_Xml_Function` is a function that returns XML.

When I run it, I receive an empty root "things" node e.g. (). How do I return the XML from the function as a child node of `<thing>`? I am using SQL Server 2005.

```
create procedure dbo.Ordex_Select_Things_as_Xml(
 @UserID uniqueidentifier
 ,@ThingID uniqueidentifier = null
 ,@Recursive bit = 1
)
as
begin try

--- Some other stuff here...

select top 1
   LastUpdated.LastUpdatedDate as '@lastUpdatedDate'  
   ,(
      dbo.Ordex_Select_Things_as_Xml_Function(@UserID, @ThingID, 1, 1)
)
from dbo.LastUpdated
   order by LastUpdated.LastUpdatedDate desc
      for xml path('things'), type

--- Some other stuff here...

end try
```

Comment: Why do you want to do xml from sql ? you probably should generate it outside.

Comment: @ykatchou - there is a lot of recursion going on in dbo.Ordex_Select_Things_as_Xml_Function as the rows have parent child relationships - being that I am using Microsoft C#.Net I'd imagine it would take considerably longer to do this via Linq.

Comment: I don't know exactly the enviromnent, but it could be quite heavy on the database... so it's depends of the load of the database and the client

Comment: @ykatchou - either way, this still does not answer the question.  I am trying an alternate solution, but it'd be much easier if I can do this all on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can not tell why your code does not work. Here is a sample that works. You might apply what I do to your case and figure out the difference.

The function returning xml

```
create function [dbo].[XMLFunc]() returns xml
as
begin
  return '<root><item>1</item><item>2</item></root>'
end
```

A query using XMLFunc

```
declare @TestTable table (id int)
insert into @TestTable values (1)
insert into @TestTable values (2)

select
  tt.id,
  [dbo].[XMLFunc]() 
from @TestTable as tt
for xml path('things')
```

Resulting xml

```
<things>
  <id>1</id>
  <root>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
  </root>
</things>
<things>
  <id>2</id>
  <root>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
  </root>
</things>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Now why can't I do that; I'll check it out.

Comment: Function `dbo.Ordex_Select_Things_as_Xml_Function` probably has some error in it.